# Use Ghostscript to convert every file in a folder automatically

Tags: macos, pdf, tiff, ghostscript

At the moment I'm using this command to convert file X.pdf to X.tif .

`gs -q -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -r300 -dBATCH -dPDFFitPage -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=tif/X.tif pdf/X.pdf`

Is there a smooth way to do the equivalent of

`gs -q -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -r300 -dBATCH -dPDFFitPage -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=tif/*.tif pdf/*.pdf` as one would do with say search queries? (I replaced the X with *) It obviously doesn't work with this method, but maybe there is a similiar syntax?
Or am I going to have to write a batch file or something like that?

PS: Im on OSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving this as `tif2pdf` in the directory containing subdirectories `tif` and `pdf`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change into the "tif" directory to find the input files
cd tif || { echo ERROR: Subdirectory tif not found; exit 1; }

# Loop through all files ending in ".tif"
for f in *.tif; do

   # Determine output filename
   out=${f%%tif}
   out="../pdf/${out}pdf"

   # Show the command we would run
   echo gs -q -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -r300 -dBATCH -dPDFFitPage -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile="$out" "$f"
done
```

Then go in that directory in Terminal and make this script executable with:

```
chmod +x tif2pdf
```

Then run it with:

```
./tif2pdf
```

At the moment, it does nothing, except show you what it would do. If you like the appearance of the commands it makes up, edit the script and remove the word `echo` in the penultimate line and run it again to actually do the conversions.

**Sample Output**

```
gs -q -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -r300 -dBATCH -dPDFFitPage -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=../pdf/a.pdf a.tif
gs -q -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -r300 -dBATCH -dPDFFitPage -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile=../pdf/b.pdf b.tif
```

I suggest running it on a **COPY** of your files first.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly, you're a genius! You did it the wrong way (TIF -> PDF as opposed to PDF->TIF), but I corrected it.

Comment: Oops, sorry! I am so accustomed to the last file in the command being the output file with all the programs I normally use!